# How does ASP.NET identify a request and match it to a previous server side session?

Tags: asp.net, session, server-side

How does ASP.NET identify a request and match it  to a previous server side session?

E.G:

Client sends first request, server side, setups a session variable. (e.g loggedIn)
Request two comes in, how does the server match this request to the session it created last time? (e.g mac address, ip address etc.)?

I am interested in how this is **secure**.

Comment: cookies or url mangling. The same ways (pretty much) that any other server side technology would do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two basic ways: a cookie and uri.

In a **cookie** mode, the `ASPNET_SessionId` cookie is appended to the very first response. The id can change but stays the same as soon as first item is put into the session. You can change the name of the cookie.

In a **cookieless** mode, the uri gets modified and the session id becomes part of it. Instead of http://foo.bar/qux you have http://foo.bar/(sessionid)/qux

Both modes are handled automatically depending on the configuraion (`web.config`, session section).

The security mostly depends on a secure channel. The cookie/url can be sniffed and reused if transmitted over unencrypted wire.